# (Total and Surjective) Relation - arrows

Tags: math-mode

I am looking for following symbols:

Total Relation: <<->
Surjective Relation: <->>
Total surjective Relation: <<->>

This is the sort of thing I’m looking for ([source](http://handbook.event-b.org/current/files/EventB-Summary.pdf)):

[image]

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you point to some source showing the symbols you're after?

Comment: http://handbook.event-b.org/current/files/EventB-Summary.pdf  
Relations (5.4 - 5.6)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  You should start by seeing whether http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/15925 leads you to the correct symbols.

Comment: I guess that they are using a trick, a kind of two arrows with negative space.

Comment: @egreg, the arrow tips from `amssymb` does not match with the default arrow tips (compare `$S\mathrel{\parbox[b]{0pt}{$\twoheadleftarrow$}\rightarrow }T$`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a way to build symbols like in the document you link to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\negjoinrel}{\mathrel{\mkern3mu}}
\newcommand{\rlaprel}[1]{\mathrel{\mathrlap{#1}}}
\newcommand{\rel}{\rlaprel{\leftarrow}\negjoinrel\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\trel}{\rlaprel{\leftarrow}\negjoinrel\rlaprel{\leftarrow}\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\srel}{\rlaprel{\leftarrow}\rlaprel{\rightarrow}\negjoinrel\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\tsrel}{\rlaprel{\leftarrow}\negjoinrel\rlaprel{\leftarrow}
                    \joinrel\rlaprel{\rightarrow}\negjoinrel\rightarrow}


\begin{document}
\noindent
$A\rel B\trel C\srel D\tsrel E$

\noindent$\rel$\\$\trel$\\$\srel$\\$\tsrel$
\end{document}
```

You can see that they all have the same width.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want?

```
$\ll \gg$
```

[image]

Or this (from `amssymb`):

```
$\twoheadleftarrow \twoheadrightarrow \rightarrowtail \leftarrowtail$
```

[image]

Comment: The second examples (\twoheadleftarrow,...) needs an > on the right side.

Comment: Check here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf